# tomcat8.exe consumes lot of CPU/memory if tomcat is hosted as a windows service

Tags: java, tomcat, windows-services, tomcat8

I have a web application hosted on tomcat. It works perfectly fine if I run the tomcat by double clicking startup.bat file. However same application start showing lot of performance issues (high CPU and memory) if i deploy it as windows service. I am using following command to install it as a service

> > service install tomcat

Can anybody tell why it has performance issues if I install it as a windows service? Not sure what is difference as both are starting same tomcat server.

Atul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue got resolved by setting the memory configuration after installation of tomcat as a service. I referred this link https://plavc.wordpress.com/2012/02/08/tomcat-service-on-windows/

Atul